# CSS Text after div

Tags: css

```
.legend {
display: table;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 10px/10px;
```

}

```
<div style="background: orange" class="legend"></div> New Order
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tx1n99f/

I want the text "New Order" appears next to the round box instead of appearing down. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Add `float: left;` to .legend

Comment: Ok thanks, and what if I want to have the "New Order" centered to the div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the `display` property value to `inline-block` will do that.

```css
.legend {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    vertical-align: middle;/* Ensures that the text is vertically aligned in the middle */
}
```

```html
<div class="legend"></div> New Order
```

Comment: Looks like OP also [needs the text centered vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641416/css-text-after-div#comment43701587_27641416).  If you don't mind my suggesting so, you could also add `vertical-align:middle` to the `.legend` rule

Comment: @JosephMarikle Your suggestion is perfect and I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

To show the text next to the box and give it the proper line-height you can use the code below:

```css
.legend-wrapper {
  line-height: 40px; /* Same as the height of the block */
}

.legend {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add some between text and block */
}
```

```html
<div class="legend-wrapper">
    <div class="legend"></div> New Order
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```css
display: inline-table;
```

instead of

```css
display: table;
```

```css
.legend {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend"></div> New Order
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just put your text into a span tag and only give line-height property to span tag.then it will be at center next to the .legend box

New Order